# Re enabling Location Services

Tags: android

After I disable location services on my phone and then enable them `getLastKnownLocation()` returns null although the provider it used is enabled.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Also, if I open Google maps app and then return to my app it seems to solve the problem.

Code:

```
private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            boolean enabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                Log.d("DebuggingLocation", "Skipped " + provider + " " + String.valueOf(enabled));
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }
```

Logs:

```
D/DebuggingLocation: Skipped passive true
D/DebuggingLocation: Skipped gps true
D/DebuggingLocation: Skipped network true
```

Comment: The "last known location" isn't updated automatically. It's reset when you disable location services and some app needs to request lcoation updates for there to be a "last known location". In your example Google Maps does that. Ideally your app should request location updates itself if it's important to have a location -- and to have an up-to-date location as the "last known location" might not be valid anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by requesting location updates for passive, gps and network providers.